# How to deal with this multiple inheritance?

Tags: php, class, design-patterns, multiple-inheritance

I am currently working on an MVC based project (no frameworks) using [RedBean](http://www.redbeanphp.com) as my ORM layer. RedBean allows me to [create models](http://www.redbeanphp.com/manual/models_and_fuse) by extending the `RedBean_SimpleModel` class:

```
MyModel extends RedBean_SimpleModel{

}
```

The problem is that I also use dependency injection. There's a special abstract class called `AContainer` that classes who wish to have access to the DI Container may extend. This allows the dependency injection framework to inject a copy of the DI Container into that class via a method during the creation of an object. Then, one can use `$this->get('classname');` to get something from the DI Container.

In this instance, I need my model to extend both `RedBean_SimpleModel` and `AContainer`. But we all know that multiple inheritence is fraught with [problems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem).

Besides making a copy of `RedBean_SimpleModel` and calling it something like `CModel` and then modifying it to extend `AContainer` as shown below, are there any patterns or ways to solve this problem?

```
class CModel extends AContainer{
  //copy all the methods from RedBean_SimpleModel and paste it here.
}
```

Comment: Uhm, why for following DI idea you need to inherit **all** your classes from the base one?! Prefer delegation over inheritance (c)

Comment: @zerkms, please elaborate. Symfony2 also uses a similiar class for container injection: http://api.symfony.com/2.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerAware.html

Comment: DI/IoC has nothing to do with required inheritance. It is all just about the way you retrieve dependent objects. I'd prefer to have a separated container object (that isn't parent for all my classes) and use it anywhere I need.

Comment: @zerkms, my container injection is also done via a method, infact it works exactly like SF2's.

Comment: then I don't see any reason to use the common parent for all of them. Just split your container to another hierarchy.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. Please post an answer with an example.

Comment: Why do you use DI here, does it make any sense at all? I'd rather inject an object through Interface not a Class. Extract base interface of YourModel (all you models) and make it implementing marker interface that will show it can be injected.

Comment: @idm: `AContainer` currently defines a private variable called `$_container` to hold a reference to the container. It also contains `setContainer()` to inject the container as well as a helper function `get()` to get things from the container. If this is turned into an interface, all of that would have to go. Where should I put the code for the above functions?

Comment: Did you write the container by your own? I'm afraid you've missed something important on DI because this way doesn't let its advantages to be provided and of course it makes you to inherit each class from the base. Please, have a look at existing frameworks and use 1 or maybe rewrite the existing like this: http://www.davegardner.me.uk/blog/2009/11/23/php-dependency-strategies-dependency-injection-and-service-locator/

Comment: @idm: I am actually using a modified copy Yadif (https://github.com/beberlei/yadif). From the link you have posted, it looks like only the `factory` gets the container injected to it right after creation. Are you saying that symfony2's method of getting access to the container by extending `ContainerAware`: `class MyClass extends ContainerAware` is bad?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you don't need dependency injection with RedBeanPHP models. You can use it from RedBean_Facade though if you like.

The RedBeanPHP models are attached to beans on the fly, so they are already decoupled. There is no dependency between a bean and a RedBeanPHP model. You can test your models independently.